# How can i read gzip which was came from server as http response

Tags: android, http, gzip

Hi Am developing an Android app. Am getting response from server in gZip format how can i read this gzip inputStream.I post my code below please suggest me any thing wrong.Thanks in Advance.

```
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(LaunchActivity.client.getParams(),  
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(LaunchActivity.client.getParams(), 10000);

        HttpGet post = new HttpGet(localUrl);

        HttpResponse response = LaunchActivity.client.execute(post);
        post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        post.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");


        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= 200 ||response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 300)
        {
            //is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            System.out.println("this is input stream from server====== "+is);

             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              if (entity != null) {
                is = entity.getContent();
                Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
                if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
                }
                String resultString = convertStreamToString(is);
                System.out.println("resultString========   "+resultString);
                is.close();
                String rst = decompresss(resultString);
                System.out.println("rst==== "+rst);

               // return resultString;
              }

  I got respose as below format i.e
 x��X�o�6�W=�(R����nkQ����Q<ZJl�#)gZ��}g%v[��t�`X�N���}w<�c���G�Y��w�]|��
```

Comment: I think you should be creating a new GZIPInputStream variable, instead of reassigning `is`.

Comment: How can i do please send me any sample.

Comment: `GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(is);`

Comment: I tried above code but no use.